# Convert .txt to .csv in shell

Tags: linux, shell, csv, awk

I have a text file:

```
ifile.txt
1  4    22.0  3.3 2.3
2  2    34.1  5.4 2.3
3  2    33.0 34.0 2.3
4 12     3.0 43.0 4.4
```

I would like to convert it to a csv file:

```
ofile.txt
ID,No,A,B,C
1,4,22.0,3.3,2.3
2,2,34.1,5.4,2.3
3,2,33.0,34.0,2.3
4,12,3.0,43.0,4.4
```

I was trying with this, but not getting the result.

```
(echo "ID,No,A,B,C" ; cat ifile.txt) | sed 's/<space>/<comma>/g' > ofile.csv
```

Comment: Does ifile.txt contain tabs, or sequences of spaces?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`awk` may be a bit of an overkill here. IMHO, using `tr` for straight-forward substitutions like this is much simpler:

```
$ cat ifile.txt | tr -s '[:blank:]' ',' > ofile.txt
```

Comment: tr -s '[:blank:]' ',' < csv >ofile.txt     ,  cat command can be prevented.

Comment: I prefer starting with a `cat` in most cases - it's easier (IMHO) to read when you have a single execution flow from left to right. If this is for a onetime conversion, the performance overhead of having to execute `cat` would be negligible. If this is part of a system that executes dozens of these per second, you're probably right.

Comment: So you say `awk` is overkill but then use `cat` ;-)

Comment: @fedorqui yeah, I guess that makes it harder to justify such a statement :-)

Comment: `<ifile.txt tr -s ... >ofile.txt` Doesn't that preserve the flow from left to right?

Answer (score 28):

Only sed and nothing else

```
sed 's/ \+/,/g' ifile.txt > ofile.csv
```

cat ofile.csv

```
1,4,22.0,3.3,2.3
2,2,34.1,5.4,2.3
3,2,33.0,34.0,2.3
4,12,3.0,43.0,4.4
```

Comment: Some description would be nice.

Answer (score 8):

here is the awk version
   `awk 'BEGIN{print "ID,No,A,B,C"}{print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5}' ifile.txt`

output:

```
ID,No,A,B,C 
1,4,22.0,3.3,2.3 
2,2,34.1,5.4,2.3 
3,2,33.0,34.0,2.3
4,12,3.0,43.0,4.4
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply do it using **awk**  command .

```
 awk '{
     printf("%d, %d, %.1lf, %.1lf,%.1lf\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5); 
 }'  input.txt > output.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this ..

```
tr -s " " < ifile.txt | sed 's/ /,/g' > ofile.txt
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1,4,22.0,3.3,2.3
2,2,34.1,5.4,2.3
3,2,33.0,34.0,2.3
4,12,3.0,43.0,4.4
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility, not necessarily the best, is:

```
 sed -e '1i\
 ID,No,A,B,C' -e 's/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/,/g' ifile.txt
```

Insert the heading before line 1; change each sequence of one or more space-like characters to a comma.  The line break is necessary in traditional (POSIX standard — in this case, BSD or Mac OS X) `sed`; GNU `sed` allows you to use:

```
/opt/gnu/bin/sed -e '1i\' -e 'ID,No,A,B,C' -e 's/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/,/g'
```

Output:

```
ID,No,A,B,C
1,4,22.0,3.3,2.3
2,2,34.1,5.4,2.3
3,2,33.0,34.0,2.3
4,12,3.0,43.0,4.4
```

Alternatively, and more simply, have `sed` deal with the file and use `echo` to add the header, as you did in outline:

```
{
echo "ID,No,A,B,C"
sed -e 's/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/,/g' ifile.txt
} > ofile.txt
```

On review, this is probably what I'd use.

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
cat filename | column -t -s ","
```

We can convert flat file into csv format in unix server

Comment: Column is a useful tool, but it can introduce spaces into the data because it keeps the columns aligned.  So in this example, the 12 in the 2nd cell of the last row will cause the previous rows to include a space after each number.  "4 ", "2 ", "2 "